# Emacs generate values based on system-type in an early return schema

Tags: elisp

I try to generate values from the `system-type` like in an common Pascal function with a early return schema:

```pascal
{ ASSUMING system_type is a global VAR }
FUNCTION font_name: String
BEGIN
  result :='Courier';
  IF system_type = 'darwin'    THEN Exit('Menlo');
  IF system_type = 'gnu/linux' THEN Exit('Monospace');
END;
```

But cannot find the right expression:

The snippet

```lisp
(defmacro font-name ()
  (declare (indent defun))
  `(when (eq system-type 'darwin)    "Menlo")
  `(when (eq system-type 'gnu/linux) "Monospace")
   "Courier")
```

gives me always "Courier" despite having system-type 'darwin.

This one works but with nested if else...

```lisp
(defun i4w-editor-font ()
   (if (eq system-type 'darwin)
       "Menlo"
       (if (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
          "Monospace"
          "Courier")))
```

Is there a possibility to write an 'early-return' schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is: don't define a macro if there's no need to, and there's no need for that to be a macro.  Macros are a whole separate topic, but: As with the return value of a function, a macro's expansion is the evaluation of the *final* form of its definition, and hence *any* call to your macro expands to `"Courier"`.

> This one works but with nested if else...

There are other conditional constructs:

```el
(defun i4w-editor-font ()
  "Return font according to `system-type'."
  (cl-case system-type
    ('darwin "Menlo")
    ('gnu/linux "Monospace")
    (t "Courier")))
```

Comment: See `C-h i g (elisp)Conditionals` and `C-h i g (cl)Conditionals` for details of what's available as standard.